# #296 Requires extended permissions: create_event while creating fb event in titanium

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium, titanium-modules

All am trying to do is create an event in my titanium based android app..What is wrong with this piece of code? Has anything changed on facebooks end that needs to be checked before setting the permission? I always end up getting the alert as *'#296 Requires extended permissions: create_event'* Cant find anything relavent for my error code.

```
createEvent.addEventListener('click', function() {

    var fb = require('facebook');
    fb.appid = "2007090666xxxxx";
    fb.permissions = ['publish_stream', 'read_stream', 'create_event'];
    if (!fb.loggedIn) {
        fb.authorize();
    } else {
        //showAI(L("createFbEvent"));
        var postResult = function(e) {
            var s = '';
            if (e.success) {
                //hideAI();
                s = L("eventSuccess");

                if (!e.result && !e.data) {
                    //hideAI();
                    s = L("reqCancelled");
                }
            } else if (e.cancelled) {
                //hideAI();
                s = L("reqFailTry");
            } else {
                //hideAI();
                s = "reqFail";
                if (e.error) {
                    s += "; " + e.error;
                }
            }
            openAlert("Facebook", s);
            win.close();
        };

        var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, 'logo.png');
        var blob = f.read();
        var data = {
            name : nameField.value,
            description : descField.value,
            start_time : userRows.fieldByName('fbStart'),
            end_time : userRows.fieldByName('fbEnd'),
            picture : blob,
            location : "GLand"
        };
        fb.requestWithGraphPath('me/events', data, 'POST', postResult);
    }
});
```

Comment: The thing that has changed on Facebook’s end is that you can not create events via API any more with v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cbroe said, the `create_event` permission was deprecated with the introduction of Graph API v2.0:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

> `create_event` is no longer available.

Comment: also, publish_stream is deprecated since years, and read_stream will most likely not get approved :)